# Add Sequence to an existing column in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequence

I recently migrated a product table from SQL Server to Snowflake, and I'm attempting to add a sequence to an existing prod_id column in this table. The goal is to have the product id automatically generated and incremented by 1 when a new product is added to the table.

Here is the sequence I've created:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE prod_id_seq START 11123 INCREMENT 1;
```

However, the query I used to apply the sequence to the prod_id column seems to be incorrect:

```
UPDATE product_table
SET prod_id DEFAULT prod_id_seq.NEXTVAL;
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in correcting the query. Thank you!

Comment: UPDATE changes the data in a table. If you want to change a table definition then you need to use ALTER

Comment: thank you. I changed it to ALTER product_table
ALTER COLUMN prod_id SET DEFAULT prod_id_seq.NEXTVAL; and similar queries. None of them are working. I walk through the documentation of using sequence in snowflake. I didn't find help information for adding a sequence to an existing table and column. Please let me know if I miss any thing. I'm new to Snowflake.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column#usage-notes
To change the default sequence for a column, the column must already have a default sequence. You cannot use the command ALTER TABLE ... SET DEFAULT <seq_name> to add a sequence to a column that does not already have a sequence

Comment: I did lots of search online but haven't see information for how to add it to an existing column. So I have to add the sequence when table is created and there is no way to apply it to the column later, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

The following is documented by Snowflake - just not necessarily where you might find it. The ALTER TABLE...ALTER COLUMN SET DEFAULT... statement only works when the table/column already has a default and you want to change it. It is not possible to set a default on an existing column if that column wasn't initially created with a default.

The only solution I can think of is as follows:

1. Create a new column in the table with a default of the sequence you want to use
2. Copy the data from the existing column/update the new column with the appropriate values
3. Drop/rename the existing column
4. Rename the new column to the old column

Comment: Hi, thank your for responding to my post. This is one of the queries I tried but none of them worked: ALTER TABLE PRODUCT_TABLE
ADD COLUMN PRODUCT_ID INT DEFAULT prod_id_seq.NEXTVAL; I have also reviewed the Snowflake documentation on creating sequences, using sequences, and adding columns. However, I haven't found any information on how to add a sequence while adding a new column to an existing table. Could you please provide a working query if possible? Thanks a lot!